# How to read a stored Hashtable from text file?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a `Hashtable<String, String>table` contains data to be stored in a text file , I stored it as an `Object` like this way:

```
Hashtable<String, String>table1=new Hashtable<String,String>();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(table1);
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

Then I tried to read it like an `Object` as I had stored it like this way:

```
Hashtable<String, String>table2=new Hashtable<String,String>();
FileInputStream reader=new FileInputStream(file);;
ObjectInputStream buffer=new ObjectInputStream(reader);
Object obj=buffer.readObject();
table2=(Hashtable<String, String>)obj;
buffer.close();
reader.close();
```

but the problem is `table2` still null !! I think the problem is in the way of reading, please any useful way of reading ?

Comment: (1) Don't use `Hashtable` in new code. Use `HashMap` instead. (2) If it's a `String,String` and the keys are safe to use in a properties file, use that format instead. Built-in read/write support and very easy to work with by hand.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for me. Maybe you are reading the wrong file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a [`HashMap<String, String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of `Hashtable<String, String>` and program to the [`Map<String,String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface, I would also suggest you use [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), finally make sure to store something in your `Collection` before you serialize it.

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "test.ser");
Map<String, String> table1 = new HashMap<>();
table1.put("Hello", "world");
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);) {
    oos.writeObject(table1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);) {
    Map<String, String> table = (Map<String, String>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(table);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
{Hello=world}
```

Comment: @Sid My assumption is the `Hashtable` was empty, so OP wasn't getting anything with an iterator. OP doesn't exactly show us where `table2` is still `null`.

Comment: Oh, ok, so it's nothing to do with using Hashtable, right?

Comment: @Sid Not directly. But using `Hashtable` in new code is discouraged. It was retained for old code like `StringBuffer` and `Vector` and `StringTokenizer`.